# Ionic: AppendUserAgent not working

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to follow the cordova documentation for [AppendUserAgent](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/config.html) to add an additional string to our `User-Agent` headers.

So I added this to the config.xml file:
`<preference name="AppendUserAgent" value="test"/>`

But when I run the app on my device and inspect the network, the `User-Agent` request header is unchanged.

Is this a limitation with ionic or something I'm doing wrong? I'm running ionic **1.7.10** and cordova **5.4.1**.

Comment: What device are you testing on?

Comment: Testing on Android and iOS. Seems like the problem resolved itself. Not sure if I just needed to upgrade ionic or if re-adding the platforms fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

The solution for a preference update about `AppendUserAgent` or `OverrideUserAgent` is always a remove/add platform using for Android:

```
cordova platform remove andoird

cordova platform add android
```